# "The implication being that" vs. "the implication is that"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, expressions

> Most of the time, the candidate selected by students as looking the
> most competent was also the one who’d had real life electoral success,
> the implication being that voters too had been swayed by the
> candidates’ appearance (there’s little evidence that appearance and
> competence actually correlate).

Can one replace *being* in

> *the implication being that*

with *is* or *was*?

Comment: How about "implying that" or better yet "suggesting that".

Comment: I think you would have to start a new sentence at "The implication..." for either of your two suggestions to work.

Comment: Right. Change the comma to a period, capitalize _The_, and substitute _is_ for _being_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not without making other changes.  If you did, you would get

> Most of the time, the candidate selected by students as looking the most competent was also the one who’d had real life electoral success,

followed by

> the implication **is** that voters too had been swayed by the candidates’ appearance

which is a comma splice.

You could split this into two or three sentences to avoid this problem, and the result is certainly no worse:

> Most of the time, the candidate selected by students as looking the most competent was also the one who’d had real life electoral success.  The implication is that voters too had been swayed by the candidates’ appearance.  There’s little evidence that appearance and competence actually correlate.